# Ошибка sql - Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения. Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eсть две таблицы. Первая  - главная, в ней вся информация, которая у меня есть. Во второй - id (который я создал через IDENTITY (1,1)), код здания, NameRus, NameEng. Вторая таблица, по сути, является фрагментом первой, из которой я выгрузил данные, только id сделал сам, чтобы потом привязать.
[image: Таблицы]
Я хочу перенести id в основную таблицу вместо уникального кода здания (хочу оптимизировать основную таблицу и раскидать данные по нескольким, дабы в случае чего обратиться к ним).
Попытался сделать с помощью вот такого запроса:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.MAIN_TABLE
SET dbo.MAIN_TABLE.buildingid = (
SELECT dbo.UniqueIDTable.id
FROM dbo.MAIN_TABLE INNER JOIN
 dbo.UniqueIDTable ON dbo.UniqueIDTable.buildingid = dbo.MAIN_TABLE.buildingid)
```

Выдает ошибку

> Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения. Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано

Не могу понять, почему, ведь у меня ключевой айдишник разный для каждого кода здания. Что я делаю не так?

Пробовал просто вывести id с кодами зданий на экран - все было ОК. Забыл уточнить - в **первой таблице коды зданий могут повторяться** (в ней записаны элементы, принадлежащие зданию)

Comment: Пробовал просто вывести id с кодами зданий на экран - все было ок.
Забыл уточнить - в первой таблице коды зданий могут повторяться (в ней записаны элементы, принадлежащие зданию)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема вашего запроса в подзапросе:

```
SELECT dbo.UniqueIDTable.id
FROM dbo.MAIN_TABLE INNER JOIN
 dbo.UniqueIDTable ON dbo.UniqueIDTable.buildingid = dbo.MAIN_TABLE.buildingid
```

Если он возвращает несколько одинаковых значений, то нужно сделать так:

```
UPDATE dbo.MAIN_TABLE
SET dbo.MAIN_TABLE.buildingid = (
SELECT TOP (1) dbo.UniqueIDTable.id
FROM dbo.MAIN_TABLE INNER JOIN
 dbo.UniqueIDTable ON dbo.UniqueIDTable.buildingid = dbo.MAIN_TABLE.buildingid)
```

**Но!** Эта конструкция изменит **все** значения в таблице `dbo.MAIN_TABLE` на одно, то что вернет подзапрос + она делает **не то что вам нужно**.

Вот запрос под вашу задачу:

```
UPDATE dbo.MAIN_TABLE
SET dbo.MAIN_TABLE.buildingid = dbo.UniqueIDTable.id
FROM dbo.MAIN_TABLE 
INNER JOIN dbo.UniqueIDTable ON dbo.UniqueIDTable.buildingid = dbo.MAIN_TABLE.buildingid;
```

Comment: нужно сделать так, чтобы заработало, но не факт что это будет соответствовать ожиданиям автора.

Comment: я уже так попробовал. и у меня в основной базе всем зданиям присвоился одинаковый id, а он-то для каждого здания уникален.  
>Эта конструкция изменит все значения в таблице dbo.MAIN_TABLE  
этого я и добиваюсь - нужно поменять все коды зданий на id из второй таблицы

Comment: @Belyashik дописал ответ.

Comment: @teran учел и то и то.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, спасибо за помощь! но это немного не то, что мне нужно. еще раз - мне нужно перенести id из второй таблицы в первую при условии `dbo.UniqueIDTable.id = dbo.UniqueIDTable.building id`, т.е., чтобы в первой таблицы стоял не "Код_здания1", а соответствующий ему id, равный 1. И так далее, не "Код_здания2", а 2. Я отредачил свой вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста, добавил картинку для понимания вопроса. Ну и повторюсь, что в первой таблицы коды зданий могут повторяться.

Comment: @Belyashik ну так поправили бы поле на которое нужно поменять, видно же что я ошибся. Изменил. Теперь верно?

Comment: @NickProskuryakov, честно говоря, догадался так поменять, но решил не рисковать и подождать Вас. Большое спасибо - всё заработало!